# ¿Como puedo resolver este problema en un juego de preguntas hecho en python?

Tags: python, game

tengo esta actividad para la escuela pero al momento de correr  el juego me muestra un error al momento de llamar la funcion main para dentro de ella llamar la funcion question y que empieze el juego. Me dice que algo está mal en la linea 95 de mi código ¿Alguien me podría ayudar? Se lo agradecería bastante.

```
questions = [
  ["¿Cómo se llama la hembra del caballo?: \n(A) Mula   \n(B) Burra   \n(C) Yegua   \n(D) Potrillo\n\n", "C"],
  ["¿Qué famosa pintura también es conocida como “La Gioconda”?: \n(A) El Grito   \n(B) La Mona Lisa   \n(C) La Ultima cena   \n(D) El Nacimiento de Venus\n\n", "B"],
  ["¿Cuál es la capital de Colombia?: \n(A) Barranquilla   \n(B) Bogotá   \n(C) Cartagena   \n(D) Medellín\n\n", "B"],
  ["¿Cuáles son los colores primarios?: \n(A) Verde, Amarrillo y Azul    \n(B) Amarillo, Azul y Rojo   \n(C) Verde, Amarillo y Rojo   \n(D) Rojo, Azul y Verde\n\n", "B"],
  ["¿Cuántos gramos hay en una Onza?: \n(A) 32gr.   \n(B) 28gr.   \n(C) 500gr.   \n(D) 250gr.\n\n", "B"],
  ["¿Cuántos días tiene febrero en un año bisiesto?: \n(A) 29   \n(B) 30   \n(C) 31   \n(D) 27\n\n", "A"],
  ["¿Qué elemento tiene como símbolo la letra Ag?: \n(A) Oro   \n(B) Argón   \n(C) Plata   \n(D) Manganeso\n\n", "C"],
  ["¿Cuál es la capital de Canadá?: \n(A) Toronto   \n(B) Ontario   \n(C) Ottawa   \n(D) Montreal\n\n", "C"],
]
numQuestions = 8

def question():
  print("--------------------------- QUIZ GAME ------------------------------")
  players = {}
  playersCount = int(input("¿Cuantos jugadores participarán?:"))
  for i in range(playersCount):
    player = "Jugador " + str(i + 1)
    players[player] = []
  random.shuffle(questions)

  for player in players:
    score = 0
    question_selection = 0
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Comienza el", player)
    print("Tienes 10 segundos para resolver esa pregunta, si no, esa pregunta no te dará puntos.")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
    # Iteramos sobre la cantidad de preguntas definidas
    
  print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
  print("LA PUNTUACION DE LOS PARTICIPANTES ES:")
  # Iteramos sobre los jugadores para obtener su puntuación final
  for player in players:
    # Multiplicamos su puntuación por 100
    print(player, "con", (players[player][0]*100), "puntos")
  print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
  print("LAS RESPUESTAS CORRECTAS SON: ")
  print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
  count = 0
  for i in range(numQuestions):
    finalQuestion = questions[count][0].split(":")
    finalAnswer = questions[count][1]
    print(finalQuestion[0], ":", finalAnswer)
    count += 1

def main():
  question()
main()
```

Comment: Podrias señalar donde y que mensaje de error te genera?

Comment: Dejame copiar el código a mi editor para ver cual es la linea 95 ... Nahhh ... mucho trabajo.

Comment: 1)Sería mejor la descripción del error,2) no estoy seguro pero no parece que haya 95 líneas de código ahí 3) mirando un poco querés usar radom y no está declarado en ningún lado e igual no significa que ese sea el error que mencionas.

Comment: No resumas los errores. Así como pusiste el código (bien) pon el mensaje de error completo (mal).

Answer (score 0):

En este código hay algunos fallos:

1. No tienes declarado `import random` (quiero pensar que si que lo tienes pero no aparece en el código)
2. El diccionario "players" está vacío es decir:

```
"{'Jugador 1': [], 'Jugador 2': [], 'Jugador 3': [], 'Jugador 4': [], 'Jugador 5': []}"
```

El problema de esto es que en la línea 39 te da un error en esta parte: `(players[player][0]*100)` ya que las listas están vacías y te da un error:

```
"list index out of range"
```

Deberías rellenar las listas con los puntos de cada jugador previamente para después poder trabajar con ello. Ese es el fallo principal del programa.

Resumidamente, pon algo dentro de esas listas si quieres trabajar con ellas.